# Features of use @property and @synthesize (cocos2d)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I saw in the libraries for use cocos2d strange @property and @synthesize

Standard in the examples is written as follows:

in .h

```
CGFloat minimumTouchLengthToSlide; 
}
@property(readwrite, assign) CGFloat minimumTouchLengthToSlide;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize minimumTouchLengthToSlide
```

But in lib https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCScrollLayer and another libs\extensions

in .h

```
CGFloat minimumTouchLengthToSlide_; 
}
@property(readwrite, assign) CGFloat minimumTouchLengthToSlide;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize minimumTouchLengthToSlide = minimumTouchLengthToSlide_;
```

What is the meaning of this code?

Why they changed minimumTouchLengthToSlide to minimumTouchLengthToSlide_ and added minimumTouchLengthToSlide = minimumTouchLengthToSlide_;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its often considered good practice to name the instance variable different from the property. The resoning behind this is that in that case you cannot accidently use the instance variable instead of the property. This is not that important when using value types such as integers and floats but more important when using reference types on `retain` properties. Consider a property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
...
@synthesize myString;
```

The compiler takes care of retaining the string when you do `self.myString = someString`. But when you write `myString = someString` you do not actually use the property but rather the variable directly and no retaining will take place. This can lead to zombies, leaks etc. By giving the instance variable a different name like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
...
@synthesize myString = myString_;
```

you can no longer write `myString = someString` because this would issue a compiler error. If you needed to use the instance variable directly you could always write `_myString = someString` but in practice this is rarely needed.

There are other cases when you write explicit property methods but the issue is basically the same, you cannot accidently bypass the property methods when using the second variant.

So basically this is a method to avoid unnecessary errors when handling properties (mostly retain-properties).

Comment: I say this is BAD practice. You can perfectly differentiate between the instance variable (myString) and accessing it as a property (self.myString or [self myString]). The naming convention doesn't add any value. Method parameters should be named aString or theString to avoid the "local var hides instance var" warning. The Apple guidelines make no mention of using suffixes for instance variables, but the Google guidelines do. So this coding style is coming from "outside", ie programmers who aren't used to writing ObjC code daily.

Comment: I agree so far as this is not needed for an experienced programmer but I can see the value when learning not only objective C but even programming as well as this helps remove an unnecessary mistake that nevertheless is made by many beginners in the field (and can lead to rather nasty bugs). In any case code conventions have always been a source of discussion and every programmer has to decide on her/his own. In any case I (personally ;-) would say an underscored instance variable name, that in most cases is never used by itself, does not do any harm if one decides to use them.

Comment: Agree with TriPhoenix, I think this is a useful way to prevent memory management bugs. Which "adds value".

Answer (score 0):

`@property` and `@synthesize` are a really cool feature of Objective-C to allow the automatic creation of getter and setter methods. In your examples they would create:

`- (CGFloat)minimumTouchLengthToSlide` and

`- (void)setMinimumTouchLengthToSlide:(CGFloat)newLength;` for free.

`@synthesize minimumTouchLengthToSlide = minimumTouchLengthToSlide_` means they are telling Objective-C that when someone tries to access that property, then it should point at the instance variable `minimumTouchLengthToSlide_`

`readwrite,assign` describe what happens when someone sets the property. Assign means that the value is not retained, the variable is just pointed. An example of what that method might look like could be this:

```
- (void)setMinimumLengthToSlide:(CGFloat)newLength {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"minimumLengthToSlide"]; // let observers know this property is changing
    minimumLengthToSlide_ = newLength;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"minimumLenghtToSlide"];
}
```

You can read more about them [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)