# @property and @synthesize and memory bugs

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm beginner in Objective C and Cocos2D

I read [Features of use @property and @synthesize (cocos2d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145751/features-of-use-property-and-synthesize-cocos2d)

The comments were references to bugs in the memory. What are these bugs?

In my code I use:

```
//interface
{
CC_bla_bla *a; 
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) CC_bla_bla *a;


//implementation
@synthesize a;

self.a=[CC_bla_bla load_value:123123]

//dealloc
[self.a release]
self.a = nil;
```

Within a class, I always use self.a for all manipulations. Is that bad?

And in what sense to use the "instance variable" a?

Comment: Never do `[self.a release]`! `self.a = nil` releases `a`, thus you are over releasing `a`, you'll probably crash at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are most commonly used for getting things to and from other view controllers. You *can* use properties just in a certain view controller but you have to be cautious.

Since you do:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) CC_bla_bla *a;
```

That has a retain count of 1 which like you did, you must release it in the dealloc. But say you do a = [[CC alloc], etc.... Then it will have a retain count of two.

Hopefully you understand this. You will realize on your own when it is time to use properties.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are just there to associate some "metadata" to your variables which will be used when you access to this one via the object. The @synthesize directive will generate the getter and the setter of the variable using the properties config.

For example:

```
self.a = [CC_bla_bla load_value:123123]; // The object is retained because of the property

// This is equivalent to the previous line
[self setA:[CC_bla_bla load_value:123123]];

// ------
// By the same way
self.a;

// is equivalent to
[self a];

// ------
// method generated by your property
- (void)setA:(CC_bla_bla *)newA
{
    [newA retain];
    [a release];
    a = newA;
}
```

But if you use directly the variable without passing by the object you don't use the properties value. For example:

```
a = [CC_bla_bla load_value:123123]; // The object is not retained so you may have unexcepted behaviors

// A good solution
a = [[CC_bla_bla load_value:123123] retain];
```

I hope it'll help you to clarify some points. For further reading you can watch this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2712/using-properties-in-objective-c-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing right with your code.
call your property always with self. is good.
But be ware, your code is fine only if the [CC_bla_bla loadvalue:] is not retain the created objects. If your loadvalue function have retained the created object and a property would retain it again, then it should be released twice.